# How do I enable validation in Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, validation, visual-studio-lightswitch

I transferred an Access 2010 table into a SQL Express DB and connected to it via Lightswitch.  However, I cannot toggle `Is Required`, `Allow Empty String`, or `Maximum Length` validation properties for *any* column.  Each one is disabled.  How do I enable these properties?

[image]

Comment: do you use the External DataSource for this table?

Comment: Yes, the database is located on another server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Required` checkbox is controlled on the server-side with the `Allow Nulls` property.  If the column allows null values, Lightswitch will say it's not required, and vice-versa.